# javascript function callback in C code using Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c, callback, emscripten

The task is to call a javascript function as a callback in order to show a progress of while-loop operation.
E.g.
JS:

```
var my_js_fn = function(curstate, maxstate){//int variables
console.log(curstate.toString() + " of " + maxstate.toString());
}
```

C  pseudocode:

```
int smth_that_calls_my_fn(int i, int max) {
/*
the_magic to call my_js_fn()
*/
}
    int main(){
    //....
        while (i < max){
        smth_that_calls_my_fn(i,max);
        }
    //....
    return 0;
    }
```

How can I link `smth_that_calls_my_fn` and `my_js_fn` ?

Comment: You can run inline javascript ([doc](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#calling-javascript-from-c-c)). Or you can implement C API in JS ([doc](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#implement-a-c-api-in-javascript)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic you're looking for is pretty simple -- you need to use the EM_ASM_ARGS macro.

Specifically, it can look like

```
int smth_that_calls_my_fn(int i, int max) {
  EM_ASM_ARGS({ my_js_fn($0, $1); }, i, max);
}
```

Make sure that you `#include <emscripten.h>` in your C file so that this macro exists.

The EM_ASM_ARGS macro takes JavaScript code (in braces) as the first argument, and then any other parameters you want to pass in.  In the JS code, $0 is the first argument to follow, $1 the next and so on.

I just wrote a blog entry going into detail on this topic if you want more information: http://devosoft.org/an-introduction-to-web-development-with-emscripten/